# aws waf regex pattern rule not working --rate limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, web-application-firewall

I am trying to block connection from a same ip to an endpoint ,i am doing this for 100 connection but this behaves strange

When i am trying to reach my endpoint {{URL}}/connect/token from postman for the first time i am able to connect to the endpoint as much time as possible (for example even 300 time) , for the second time when i hit the same endpoint i get 403 which is correct , not sure what makes this strange behavior

Any help much appreciated

```
resource "aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set" "url_pattern" {
  name        = "url_pattern-regex"
  description = "A regex that matches Account api Token and Authorize endpoints"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"
  regular_expression {
    regex_string = "/connect/token"
  }
  regular_expression {
    regex_string = "/connect/authorize"
  }

}

locals {
  name = "${var.environment}-${var.stack}-acl"
}


resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "x-account-acl" {
  name        = local.name
  description = "rate based statement."
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "rule-1"
    priority = 1

    action {
      count {}
    }

    statement {
      rate_based_statement {
        aggregate_key_type = "IP" //Count number of calls from IP
        limit              = 100

        scope_down_statement {
          regex_pattern_set_reference_statement {
            arn = aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.url_pattern.arn

            field_to_match {
              uri_path {}
            }

            text_transformation {
              priority = 1
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "friendly-rule-metric-name"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "friendly-metric-name"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "web_acl_association_loadbalancer" {
  resource_arn = module.alb.alb_arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.x-account-acl.arn
}
```

my postman code :

```
const postRequest = {
  url: pm.environment.get("URL") + '/connect/token',
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: {
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded:
    [
        {key: "client_id",value: pm.environment.get("Client_Id_userApi")},
        {key: "grant_type",value: "client_credentials"},
        {key: "client_secret",value: pm.environment.get("Client_Secret_userApi")},
    ]
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {

  if (error) {
    console.log(error,i);
  }
});
}
```

for me the code or configuration seems ok but it is seems a strange behavior ,